# Create ISO installation from current Ubuntu Server installation

Tags: 14.04, server, backup, iso

I have a kiosk running on Ubuntu server 14.04.3 and I would like to create an ISO file so when I want to create another kiosk all I will have to do is to install that ISO file and I'm done. To do that I tries to install `remastersys` but I just couldn't install it. It always returned with an error when I tried to install the key. All of the other installations are using a GUI which I don't have since it's an ubuntu server.

How would you create the ISO file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I ended up creating an image of my current system status is using [clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/). It was as easy as downloading the `Clonezilla Live` and install it on a USB with [Universal Usb Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) and when the computer is booting, chose to boot from the USB and follow the `Clonezilla` guided steps. I've also used [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LS6VhLDw-io) for some steps.

Answer (score 0):

Simply run this command from a live CD:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/media/[external hdd]/image.img
```

That will copy bit for bit the first hard drive into an image file (which must be on a second hard drive).  Then just run this to place that image on another  (destination) machine:

```
sudo dd if=/media/[external hdd]/image.img of=/dev/sda
```

Be careful, doing this improperly will completely destroy an installation.  Responsibility for improperly executing the instructions in this answer lies on the user.

Comment: What do you mean by "from a live CD"? I have the Ubuntu installed on a HDD and I would like to create the `img` file on a USB which is mounted at `/media/usb`

Comment: You have to have the main HDD unmounted, so you need to use a live CD (like the Try Ubuntu option on the Ubuntu CD) to transfer the image.

Comment: You could also boot off of a live USB.

Comment: That's not an option then. I've installed the ubuntu using a bootable USB.

Comment: You can boot off of that same USB and select Try Ubuntu.  That will do the same thing, just make sure that /dev/sda is not mounted.

Comment: and if I want to create the img file on that same bootable CD, is that possible? Also, how do I check if /dev/sda isn't mounted?

Comment: Do you mean saving the image on that CD?  No you can't do that.

Comment: Well, at least not easily.

Comment: To check if `/dev/sda` is unmounted: `sudo umount /dev/sda`

Comment: I see. I'm pretty sure that the SSD is `/dev/sda1`, I will try it and let you know as soon as I try it.

Comment: Don't use /dev/sda1, use /dev/sda.  /dev/sda will copy the entire disk, which is what you need.  Use `/dev/dsa`

Comment: I can't start ubuntu with `Try Ubuntu`. The only options I have when I try to boot from the USB is to install ubuntu, multiple server install, check disc for defects, test memory, boot from first hard disk (which simply returns to the same screen. Any idea?

Comment: You might need to make a second USB with the desktop version.